# EXTJS-27586 - Cannot read property 'viewModel' of null

Tags: extjs, extjs7

In release note of 7.3.0, this ticket was marked fixed.
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/guides/whats_new/release_notes.html

But I do not see the code change as per suggested here:
https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?469880-Cannot-read-property-viewModel-of-null

May I know is this actually fixed?
This is 7.3.0.55 as I downloaded:
[image]

Comment: nop, still remains same in version 7.3.1

Comment: yeah. :( Are we going to fix it? 
Since we have moved to here rather than sencha forum. So, will there be any sencha guy looking at this and open ticket to attach to this question?

Comment: @Neo, you were able to repro the issue?  It's possible that yes in that forum they posted a patch, but it was fixed some other way in the framework.

Comment: @incutonez yup, I'm able to repro that. that's why i asked for the fix. But I could not be sure what's went wrong. I believe it throws error when i do removeAll() in the view. Anyhow, this error happen after I upgrade from 6.2.0 to 7.3.0. So, I have to apply the fix as per the forum and it solves the issue.

Comment: @Neo, I didn't see an example in that forum link for how to repro the bug.  Do you think you could supply an example, please?  Or some pseudocode of what you're doing when it throws the error?